# Leetcode longest common prefix

Tags: java

I am having a hard time following this solution. I understand we set a prefix, and loop through the remainder of the array and keep chopping the prefix until prefix fully exists in each string but why are we doing `strs[i].indexOf(output) != 0` in the while loop?

```
public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if(strs.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    String output = strs[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
        while(strs[i].indexOf(output) != 0) {
            output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: That's what's chopping it. It's removing characters from the end of `output` one at a time until `strs[i].indexOf(output) != 0` is `false` (`strs[i]` starts with `output`), then it has to do the same thing for every string in order to make sure to get the actual common prefix. Have you read the documentation on the various methods in here? This seems like something that would be covered by it.

Comment: Could add some context here? What is "this solution" a reference to? Could you link to the problem (if it is on a public website) or restate the problem in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much more understandable (and efficient) would be to use "not `startWith`."

```
    while (!strs[i].startsWith(output)) {
        output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);
    }
```

`indexOf` would also search at other positions for a substring equal to `output`.

This would be more readable as "as long as `strs[i]` does not start with the prefix, shorten the prefix by 1. An empty prefix (`output`) would exit the loop. (You might then also break out of the *for* loop.)

Answer (score 1):

`!= 0` means that the prefix string did not start at the beginning of the string. If the index `> 0` it was further into the string.  If it was `-1` it didn't exist in the string at all.  If it was `== 0` it started at the beginning.

Notice that the while loop keeps backing up using `substring` until a prefix matches the beginning.  Then it exits the while loop.  Then it continues to see if the next string contains the first and backs up until they share an equal prefix.  This continues until either a longest common prefix is returned or an empty string.